# cookies cannot access from client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, session-cookies

i'm trying to understand session and cookie using JS
i'm using express-session package to handle the session and cookie. The problem is from my client side, when i'm using postman the cookie appear

```
sessionID 92bda427-c9fd-4281-9979-a5b58b925e59
 req.session Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
    _expires: 2018-11-17T04:53:52.616Z,
    originalMaxAge: 432000000,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    domain: 'localhost' },
     __lastAccess: 1541998432616 }
    req.cookies { SID: 's:92bda427-c9fd-4281-9979- 
    a5b58b925e59.gLHHBeXoebwvFEA3Y0d9kOwLxC6ICgkbcSPU9FMmHkQ'}
```

but when i'm using client to acces the same path, the cookie just return empty object, I already checked some stackoverflow question and some said to change the secure: false and httpOnly: false, but it didn't work for me

```
sessionID d5ec7773-fc1c-4aad-9dbb-6f822107a681
req.session Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2018-11-17T04:53:58.260Z,
     originalMaxAge: 432000000,
     httpOnly: false,
     domain: 'localhost',
     secure: false } }
req.cookies {}
```

my express setting

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    return uuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost',
    path: '/',
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 7 days
    httpOnly: false,
  },
  store: new FileStore(),
  secret: 'some secret key',
  name: 'SID',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

Comment: Please share your express cookie settings.

Comment: ok just added my express setting

Comment: Can you see your cookie in the browser?

Comment: yes I can. it appear on the application - cookies - localhost section with the name and value

Comment: Did u try `xhr.withCredentials = true;` in your request?